# Subclassing UICollectionViewCell with a custom xib and contentView

Tags: ios, xib, uicollectionviewcell

I created my subclass using the Xcode UI of File > New > File… > Cocoa Touch Class (Also create xib file is checked) … Done.

I add subviews directly to the collection view cell’s `view` subview:

[image]

I’ve registered the subclass and nib with the `UICollectionView` and it’s all working great. However, when I programatically access my collection view cell’s `contentView` property to set its background colour, it doesn’t change.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(CellIdentifiers.Category, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CategoryCollectionViewCell

    let category = categoryForIndexPath(indexPath)

    cell.textLabel.text = titleForCategory(category)

    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    return cell
}
```

In lldb, my `contentView` has the address: **0x13fdc3550** and the text label’s superview (what I assumed should be the `contentView`) has the address **0x000000013fdc36b0** - so they must be different.

How do I successfully subclass `UICollectionViewCell` with a custom xib and get access to the content view via the `contentView` property?

P.s, what’s interesting is if I set this `contentView` property’s hidden to true, that works.

Comment: Try setting the background color in `collectionView(_:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:)`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn’t work

Answer (score 0):

Text Label's superView is a `UIView` you dragged into the cell. It should be a subview of cell's contentView. So when you set contentView's hidden to true all it's subviews hid too. But when you set contentView's `backgroundColor` to something the view you dragged into cell will cover it. You can check text label's superview's superview to see if it match the contentView's address in lldb.

So here you either directly change that view's backgroundColor or change your cell's layout remove that view.

Comment: I didn’t drag out `textLabel`’s superview. But should this still be the same logic?